# How Can I Add Multiple Items To An Array In PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm adding a lazyload exclude code to my functions.php and want to exclude multiple source items.

I checked [php arrays](https://php.net/manual/tr/function.array.php) for trying.

```
function rocket_lazyload_exclude_src( $src ) {
    $src[] = 'xxxxx'; //this excludes xxxxx.jpg and i want to exclude yyyyy.jpg too with adding 'yyyyy'

    return $src;
}
add_filter( 'rocket_lazyload_excluded_src', 'rocket_lazyload_exclude_src' );
```

Comment: How it is related to JavaScript ?

Comment: array code structures are similar. i didnt know. @CodeManiac

Comment: Why not just add `$src[] = 'yyyyy';`?

Comment: @dWinder because i need to exclude both xxxx.jpg and yyyy.jpg, also i want to learn.

Comment: So have both of them as `$src[] = 'xxxx'; $src[] = 'yyyyy';`. And also, the first argument of `add_filter` is the filter tag and not the callback name

Comment: @dWinder wont second one override first one?

Comment: No - as the `[]` operator in PHP is appending element to array -> so each line just add new (=append) new string to that array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function rocket_lazyload_exclude_src( $src ) {
   //Add image in array and return
    $src= array("xxxxx", "yyyyy");

    return $src;
}
add_filter( 'rocket_lazyload_excluded_src', 'rocket_lazyload_exclude_src' );
```

Comment: But in here you override the original `$src` var -> you need to append those and not create new array with them

Comment: I added both the image in array. If you see the filter code, In that code using the for each loop excluding the image. check lazyloadImages function in plugin.

Comment: @dWinder  It's not override. Just adding two image in array to exclude.

Comment: thank you both of you dWinder.
@ShivendraSingh's solution works for me.